# Print Screen key of Windows on Mac

Tags: windows-7, macbook, boot-camp, screen-capture

I've tried Win 7 on my MacBook. then I'm facing a problem of capturing the screen. I want to take the screen shot of the whole screen(including the cursor). I'm sure that I can grab it with the key "Print Screen". But I don't found any key for it on my Mac. also though Windows Snippet tools can take the whole screen, I've to use the cursor .. Thus, any solution that can help out my problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The <kbd>PrintScr</kbd> equivalent is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> according to Boot Camp help (similar content [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1220))...

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScr</kbd> (capture current window)

Comment: any particular reason for the downvote?  What I posted works for me, is backed up by documentation and is different to the other answer...

Comment: THANKS!!!!!  I don't have printscr on my mac and had been finding a shortcut to substitute it!!  I will +100 if I could!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out http://www.logicnest.com/archives/78

According to the article:

> If you’re using Boot Camp v. 1.3, Fn + F11 >now maps to print screen. You can print only the active window with Option + Fn + F11.

Comment: I've tried .. but no effect :(

Comment: Print screen only places an image on the clipboard (not desktop, unlike osx)... Did you open paint or something and "paste"?

Comment: Don't forget, you can always just hook up a regular keyboard to use the Print Screen button as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can't include a cursor in a screenshot unless you use a third party application like Paint Shop Pro (the print screen button in windows doesn't include your cursor normally). Normal print screen is straightforward though and the other two answers should work...