# Can't find the print screen key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, print-screen

I've seen this question:
[Print Screen key of Windows on Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/132961/print-screen-key-of-windows-on-mac)

But it doesn't help me.

I had a normal windows keyboard for my PC (WinXP) but the E key broke so I used an old Mac keyboard I found in the office which works well.  It basically looks like this:

[image]

How do I print screen?  There is no FN button.

Comment: Maybe you need to look at setting up an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) macro and bind it to whatever key combination you fancy. I don't use AutoHotkey myself, but I'm sure someone on here can help produce a script for you.

Answer (score 2):

- Download [screen-shot utility](http://www.screenshot-utility.com/) .
- It will run in your system tray. Give it the Hotkey Alt+0 (or any other as you prefer).
- Whenever you press the Hotkey it displays a message "Screen Captured" press on OK.
- All your captured screen will be automatically saved in your Desktop.
- You may configure it as per your needs

Answer (score 1):

You may use this alternative way to press **PrintScreen**

1. Download **On-Screen Keyboard Portable** from PortableApps.com **(Portable, Free)**
   http://portableapps.com/apps/accessibility/on-screen_keyboard_portable
2. Extract and execute it.
3. Click "psc" botton with mouse.

---

Alternatively, a screen capture freeware can do the task easily (as well as enhance productivity). With this tool, you can **define custom hotkey** or click the menu for screen capturing.

**FastStone Capture 5.3** (Last Free Version, Portable) is my personal favourite.
http://www.aplusfreeware.com/categories/mmedia/FastStoneCapture.html

Comment: The problem with using an on-screen keyboard is that it might get in the way of the screenshot?

Comment: Oh yes, why I didn't think of that. It will be still useful for capturing a window (Alt-PrintScreen), or only part of the whole screen is needed. Alternate solution added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a third-party product : My favorite is the free [Gadwin PrintScreen](http://www.gadwin.com/printscreen/).

Among many other options, you can also define your favorite shortcut key.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure, but if only the position is interpreted correctly by windows, it's this one:

[image]

Comment: Windows won't map keys based on their location on the keyboard.

Comment: Those three keys are the F14-16 keys...I'm not sure if they would be mapped to Print/Scroll/Break. That depends on what keycode they're sending.